# How to interpolate strings that represent environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

I've got this `runtime` need to replace environment variables in a plain text file. Say the file looks like this:

```
version: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  - name: $PODNAME
```

My bash script pulls out all environment vars, here `$PODNAME`.

Once I have a handle on what string tokens are environment variables, I'd like to replace them with the environment var value from the host running the script. So above, I'd replace the string `$PODNAME` with the `env` value of `$PODNAME`.

With what I have, I can list all `env` vars. But I can't seem to get the replacement done. For my toy example, I'd like to echo out both the string token and the value it should replace:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    IFS=', ' read -a array <<< $(grep -F -- "$" file.yaml | sed -e 's/          value: //' | tr '\n' ' ')
    for element in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "$element"
    done
```

I've tried stuff like this:

```
        echo "$element ${$element}"
```

I've done some searches but can't seem to find the `StackOverflow` question that already covers this weird `usecase`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 for some methods for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heredoc would have been a good approach, but doesn't jibe with what I was attempting to do:

> I'd like to echo out both the string token and the value it should replace

I was on the right track with this:

```
echo "$element ${$element}"
```

In the end, here's what worked:

```
EL=$(echo "$element" | sed 's/\$//')
echo "$element ${!EL}"
```

Upvotes for all, regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
PODNAME="foo"

cat << EOF
version: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  - name: $PODNAME
EOF
```

Output:

```
version: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  - name: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `gnu sed`, it can be done with the `e` action of `sed`.

```
$ export PODNAME=foo

$ cat file.yaml 
version: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  - name: $PODNAME

$ sed -r 's/^(.*) (\$[A-Z]+)/echo "\1 \2"/e' file.yaml
version: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  - name: foo
```

The environment variable needs to be exported for `sed` to see it's value.